# Some children elements still overflow parent div with overflow-x: scroll

Tags: css

I've just realized that in a `div` with `overflow-x: scroll` I have a horizontal scroll bar as expected but I also have some children elements that are outside the `div`.

I was expecting that the scroll bar would grow/shrink to accommodate more/less of that div children elements.

You can see this effect here (you need to inspect to see hidden elements) here, where element number 1 and 2 are hidden on the left of the parent `div`:

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/w01y50yb/

Please note that I also have inline style.
Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a outer container to the content and apply `overflow-x` and `width` to it. Check this [**updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w01y50yb/1/)

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <!-- You content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this a work around or is it the intended behavior. Seems strange to me have to add a wrapper div...

Comment: This is a workaround. It's because of `display: flex`

Comment: Sorry, but I just realized that If I have the `width: 50%` then my problem still exist and I need to have it like that not with 100%.